# LUA - How to mask only numbers in a string?

Tags: lua

I have to mask only numbers in a field using LUA script(in OptimZ tool). For e.g. I have a field which may contain transaction description as below.

•   ACH Transfer check #12345678

•   Fund transfer from acnt#12345678

In the output, only number should be masked(like below).

•   ACH Transfer check #87654321

•   Fund transfer from acnt#87654321

Please note that string length is always varying. can anyone suggest how to mask the same in LUA?

Comment: What do you even mean by "mask"?

Comment: `local s ="ACH Transfer check #12345678"; print(s:gsub("#%d+","#87654321"))`

Comment: Do you actually mean you want to reverse the numeric portion of the string? or was that not intended in your and just appears that way in the examples? before: `#12345678` after: `#87654321`

Comment: I actually want to mask the numeric part in my string.. So either by reversing the numeric portion or by applying some other masking rules.

Comment: Ah I believe you might be using mask ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing) ) in a way a programmer would not normally use it.

Answer (score 1):

From your examples I take that you want to replace the number in the strings with other numbers.

```
local text = "ACH Transfer check #12345678"
local newNumber = 87654321
local newtext = text:gsub("%d+", string.format("#%d", newNumber), 1)
```

`string.gsub(text, pattern, repl [,n])` will replace the first `n` (or all) matches of `pattern` with `repl` in `text`

I provided a more general example. Of course there are shorte ways to do it with your particular example.

Comment: Thanks Piglet.
But How do assign value to local newNumber dynamically? In my example I just reversed the value in masked output. But this value will vary dereddening on the value present in my input string.

Comment: @njain change `newNumber` too: `local newNumber = text:match("%d+"):reverse()`

Comment: you just use a number and string formatting that suits your needs. I just gave you a starting point. read the manual and find out what I used.